# Unable to install chef-server on Debian wheezy

Tags: debian, chef-infra

I am trying to install chef-server on Debian but I am failing to do so. Here are the steps I followed:

```
$ dpkg -i  chef-server-core_12.17.5-1_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package chef-server-core.
(Reading database ... 23329 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking chef-server-core (from chef-server-core_12.17.5-1_amd64.deb) ...

Setting up chef-server-core (12.17.5-1) ...
```

Below step is failing:

```
$ chef-server-ctl reconfigure
 /opt/opscode/embedded/bin/ruby: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /opt/opscode/embedded/lib/libruby.so.2.2)
```

Though I can see the package available for "Red Hat Enterprise Linux | SUSE Linux Enterprise Server | Ubuntu" from downloads.

Could anyone please help here if you would be able to compile on Debian.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the suggestions from `coderanger` and the continuous research. Finally, I end up successfully configuring the chef.
My configurations are:

1. Debian 9, 64 bit.
2. Chef-Server version: 12.17.5.
3. Chef Manage version: 2.5.8.
4. Chef development kit version: 2.4.17.

I have downloaded the above [installers](https://downloads.chef.io/) and the installation steps which are followed as below:

```
#Chef-Server
$ dpkg -i chef-server-core_12.17.5-1_amd64.deb
$ chef-server-ctl reconfigure

#Chef-Manage
$ dpkg -i chef-manage_2.5.8-1_amd64.deb
$ chef-manage-ctl reconfigure
$ chef-server-ctl reconfigure

#Chef-DK
$ dpkg -i chefdk_2.4.17-1_amd64.deb
```

It may help someone who faces the similar issue! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As stated on the download page you got that `deb` from, and noted in the question, the installer is for Ubuntu 16.04 or 14.04, both of which use a newer glibc ABI. You could try the 14.04 packages if you haven't but I think they are newer than 2.14 too, you might have to look for the last release built for 12.04 or 10.04, not even sure which those are though. Overall, we do not support installation on anything other than the stated platforms, meaning we do not recommend any version of Debian at all (for Chef Server, chef-client works fine and is 100% supported).

Comment: I tried the installer of Ubuntu 14.04 as well but no luck. Chef-12.16.14 is available for Ubuntu-12.04. Let me give a try.

Comment: Chef Server-12.6.0 installer of Ubuntu-10.04 worked for me. But I wonder why latest version installer is not supporting Debian!

Comment: Debian in general is too much of a minority OS to be worth supporting, and Debian 7 is ancient. The current gen packages should, in theory, work on Debian 9, we just don't officially support it :)

Comment: Thanks :). Latest chef-server installer worked on Debian 9.